# On Screen keyboard in Windows 8 tablet

Tags: java

using this code snippet, I am starting the On Screen keyboard process through a focus gained event from Java Swings.

```
String sysroot = System.getenv("SystemRoot");
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + sysroot + "/system32/osk.exe");
```

When the focus is lost, the key board should close. I used `proc.destroy()` to implement that.
This implementation is behaving abnormally in Windows 8 tablet. Its opening the key board on focus, not closing when focus is lost. I am running the program from Eclipse.

The same implementation worked perfectly for Windows 7 desktop. The only change is, I did not specify `cmd /c` in Windows 7. For Win 8, its not even opening the Key board, if I don't give `cmd /c`

Please suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Java & eclipse RCP):

```
    text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0)
        {
                LogUtil.logInfo("Closing OSK");

                try
                {
                    if(Settings.getBoolean(Settings.OSK_USETABTIP)) {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c taskkill /IM tabtip.exe");
                    } else {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c taskkill /IM osk.exe");
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    LogUtil.logError(e.toString());
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                String sysroot = System.getenv("SystemRoot");

                if(Settings.getBoolean(Settings.OSK_USETABTIP)) {
                    LogUtil.logInfo("Opening TabTip");
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/pathtotabtip/tabtip.exe");
                    pb.start();
                } else {
                    LogUtil.logInfo("Opening OSK");
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(sysroot + "/system32/osk.exe");
                    pb.start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogUtil.logError(e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```